# Link failed in Xcode15

Tags: ios, xcode15

Assertion failed: (false && "Malformed property list"), function getProperties, file ObjC.cpp, line 241.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tq2Tc.png)

when i use xcode15 build my project, but link failed.
How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

other link flags add "-ld64"